# Modifications to VB.NET PDF Viewer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf-viewer

Okay, I know a question LIKE this has been asked before, but none of them covered this certain toolbar. After the top and left toolbars are hidden, this little black window shows up near the bottom of the screen which allows the user to print, save, zoom, etc. They can also even open the top and left toolbars back up by clicking the Adobe logo.

As you can see, at the top of my program I have a toolbar of my own. The way my program works is a user will input data, press the 'Create Report' button and this Report Viewer window will popup. When the user Creates a Report a .PDF file named `preview.pdf` is created and that's what the user opens up. If the user doesn't like the report he can hit the X to delete it, or if he likes it he can type a File Name and Press Save. Or he can skip the saving and just print it. When the user saves the file it goes to a place that the software can retrieve at a later time. If the user presses the save button on one of the Adobe toolbars he has the option to save it where they want to. I can't have that.

Does anybody know how to disable ALL Adobe toolbars in the .NET PDF Viewer? (And yes, I know that Pressing F8 will bring them back up).

Here's the code I have now:

```
pdf.src = "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\HelloWorld.pdf"
pdf.setShowToolbar(False)
pdf.setView("fitH")
pdf.setLayoutMode("SinglePage")
pdf.setShowScrollbars(False)
pdf.setZoom(68)
```

Here's a screenshot of the Windows Form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat viewer has such switchable [options](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf).
this configuration switchs off all navigation:

```
view=FitH
scrollbar = 0
toolbar= 0
statusbar= 0
messages= 0
navpanes= 0
```